# Print string at address with radare2

Tags: radare2

I have created a very basic golang program which display a message with fmt.Println().

Here is what is see in radare2:

```
lea rcx, obj.main.statictmp_0 ; 0x4c84b0 ; "y[K"
mov qword [local_48h], rcx
lea rcx, [local_40h]        ; 0x40 ; '@' ; 64
mov qword [rsp], rcx
mov qword [local_8h], 1
mov qword [local_10h], 1
call sym.fmt.Println
```

I suppose obj.main.statictmp_0 contains my string message.

I have tried:

```
ps @obj.main.statictmp_0
```

but it does not display my message.
Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Well, GO compiled binaries might behave differently than other binaries. Can you share the binary itself? :)

Comment: go uses  counted string with no zerotermination  a pointer and size array   struct chararray { char * str , int size }   chararray[] = { "foo" ,3 ;.........}   so  0x4c84b0 in your case is pointer to  string  since you are on x64 the next qword that is 0x4c84bc will hold the string length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `pf S @obj.main.statictmp_0`. string length is at address `@obj.main.statictmp_0+8` if using 64bit or `@obj.main.statictmp_0+4` if using 32bit!

```
pf S @obj.main.statictmp_0   ; gives you string
pf p @obj.main.statictmp_0+8 ; gives you string length
```